# Mapping to Dictionary with iBATIS

Tags: .net, ibatis, datamapper

Given a simple statement, such as:

```
<statement id="SelectProducts" resultMap="???">
  SELECT * FROM Products
</statement>
```

Is it possible to get a list of dictionary objects where the keys are the column names?
ie.

```
var list = Mapper.QueryForList<IDictionary<string,string>>("SelectProducts", null);

IDictionary<string, string> dict = list[0];
// dict["id"] == "1"
// dict["name"] == "Some Product Name"
// dict["price"] == "$9.99"
// etc.
```

I'd like to generalize the result of a query to handle any number of columns/column names without mapping to specific properties on some class.

I realize the example here would fail since a result set may have duplicate (or null) column names. I've thought about a result class that holds an indexed list of key-value pairs. The key thing here is retaining the column information somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting the class attribute to HashTable in the resultMap configuration.  More details available [here](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s05.html#id383376).